# Swagger JaxRs combining generated sources with existing model

Tags: jax-rs, swagger-2.0

I am using Wildfly 9.1, swagger-jaxrs 1.5.3 and swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 2.1.3

We try to combine an API (with its own model and services) defined by swagger and our database model generated by our own generator.
Our Generator already adds the annotations needed by swagger to recognize it as resources to the API.

We now try to dynamically generate the model defined by swagger in compile time (swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) which works nice as long as we do not want to use classes of our other mode.

The two problems i have are:

1. when writing the swagger spec i use to generate the files for the new api i am not able to reference the objects defined by our database model
2. if i now add these objects to the swagger model to prevent this problem (either by adding a dummy or by generating the .json from the existing entities) The classes generated by swagger obviously expect them to be in the same package.

I am searching for a smart way to combine both approaches without losing the opportunity of developing the API by editing the swagger spec.

Comment: If you look at {{io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfig#importMapping()}} that's how they use Date for instance instead of generating a model object for it. I am trying to see how I can register my own existing models. Will post if I find the solution.

Comment: I should have said look at "CodegenConfig#typeMapping" instead actually.